# Shopify Collection page description area - make responsive

Tags: css, sass, shopify

I have a text, some images, and a video in a Shopify Collection page description text area. When the page renders on a mobile device, the content of that area does not shift to the mobile device. Does the Shopify css grid system allow for nested columns or would it be better to use Flexbox in the text area?

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: @AliceGirard I am using Out Of The Sandbox Mobilia theme

Comment: Did you contact their support? It would be useful to warn them about this issue.